# scipy linalg deterministic/non-deterministic code

Tags: python, random, scipy

I'm running this [SVD](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html) solver from `scipy` with the below code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds

features = np.arange(9,dtype=np.float64).reshape((3,3))
for i in range(10):
    _,_,V = svds(features,2)
    print i,np.mean(V)
```

I expected the printed mean value to be the same each time, however it changes and seems to cycle through a few favourite values. I'm happy to accept that behaviour as a consequence of the low level optimisation/random seeding.

What I don't quite get is why it will output the same values in the same order each time I run that script. To me it seems semi deterministic and semi non-deterministic.

This is problem is affecting some more complicated processing and it would be nice to understand it so I can at least do some hacky workaround.

Comment: Very interesting & useful question. Can't think of anything in the underlying SVD (or below) that is at all random.

Comment: Curiously, [``TruncatedSVD``](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) has ``algorithm=random`` as default. Perhaps it's a bug in the interface of ``SVD``?

Comment: @Ami `svds` uses an iterative method (ARPACK) with by default random initialization. Why it would be consistent, I don't know.

Comment: @Dougal thanks! guess I'll have to brush up on that (can't think of the rationale for it to be random at the moment).

Comment: Maybe it boils down to the question of how exactly [``numpy.random``](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) works, esp. with ``seed`` not called explicitly. Perhaps you could see if calling this (with some fixed value) immediately prior to the calls can make it deterministic again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing myself (on a tablet right now without a Python shell handy), I believe this is due to somewhat strange behavior related to the starting point for the initialization used by the approximate eigensolver library ARPACK, which is what `svds` ends up calling.

If you follow through the Python code from [`svds`](http://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py#L1624), `v0` (the starting point in question) is handled only [in `_ArpackParams`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py#L318), where it's set to zeros and the `info` parameter set to `0` if `v0 is None`; otherwise, `v0` is kept as its value and `info` is `1`. Then we go into the realm of <s>dragons</s> Fortran, calling (if the matrix is doubles) the function [`dsaupd`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC/dsaupd.f), which I didn't fully check but I'm assuming eventually calls [`cgetv0`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC/cgetv0.f) when a random starting point is requested. This function appears to [initialize the LAPACK RNG seed to 1357](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC/cgetv0.f#L194) the first time it's called.

So, if you don't make any other calls to ARPACK (or possibly other LAPACK things, not sure how these interact with one another), you're starting the RNG with the same seed every time and thus getting the same initialization points every time; thus, assuming this is the only source of randomness in the algorithm, you'll get the same sequence of answers every time.

You could hack around this by, say, calling `eigs` on a small matrix a random number of times at the start of your code.

Comment: because i know which mean values i want i ended up putting in a while loop to wait until the solver gives me a reasonable value.